# Prevent modal from closing when there is error

Tags: javascript, .net, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have made use of a generic approach where on adding a food item, a modal with a form will open to let the user add his details. However, for the check on backend for duplicate items, i can only retrieve that after the API call has finished.

The thing is I don't want the modal to be close if there is error as user has to fill all his details again.

Here is my code. I have used third party libraries for modal and toast.

food.component.ts:

```js
addFood(data: any){
    this.api.request('foodItem', 'POST', data).subscribe({
        next: (response: any) => {
            if (response.message == 'Added Successfully.') {
                this._toastService.showSuccess('Food added.');
            } else {
                this._toastService.showError(response.message);
            }
        },
        complete: () => this.getFood(),
        error: (error: any) => this._toastService.showError(error.message)
    });
}
```

food-component.html

```
 <app-custom-table [tableData]="tableData" [form]="formData" [columnArray]="columnArray" (onAdd)="addFood($event)" (onEdit)="editFood($event)"></app-custom- 
 table>
```

custom - table.component.html

```html
<button type = "button" class="btn btn-link"(click) = "openModal()"[disabled] = "isRowSelected"><span>Add</span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link"(click) = "openModal(selectedRow)"[disabled] = "isRowNotSelected"></i><span>Edit</span></button>
```

custom - table.component.ts:

```js
openModal(rowData: any = null) {
    const config: Partial<DynamicFormComponent> = {
        form: this.form,
        data: rowData
    };

    const options: NgbModalOptions = { size: 'sm', centered: true };

    const modalRef = this.ModalService.show((DynamicFormComponent), config, options).

modalRef.componentInstance.submitSubject.subscribe((result: any) => { //here getting error Property CoponentInstance does not exist in type Observable<ModalResult<unknown>>
        if (result.Success == true && result.Data) {
            if (rowData) {
                const updatedRowData = { ...rowData, ...result.Data };
                // If rowData is provided, it's an edit operation
                this.onEdit.emit(updatedRowData);
            } else { //add
                this.onAdd.emit(result.Data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

dynamic-form.html

```
 @Output() submitSub: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
 constructor(
  private activeModal: NgbActiveModal
 ){
 
 }

  onSubmit(){
  if(this.dynamicFormGroup.valid){
    this.submitSubject.next(this.dynamicFormGroup.value)  
   this.activeModal.close(this.dynamicFodmGroup.value) --not sure here
  }


  }
```

How to solve this?

***UPDATE***

```
openModal(rowData: any = null) {

const config: 
Partial<DynamicFormComponent> = {
form: this.form,
data: rowData
};

const options: NgbModalOptions = { 
size: 'sm', centered: true, 
backdrop: 'static' };

this.ModalService.
show((DynamicFormComponent), 
config, options);


 const activeSubscription =   

this.ngbModalService.
activeInstances
.subscribe((res: any) => {
this.modalRef = 
res[0].componentInstance;
});

setTimeout(() => {
this.modalRef.componentInstance.
 submitSubject
.subscribe((result: any) => {
if (result.Success == true && 
result.Data) {


  if (rowData) {
            
 this.onEdit.emit(updatedRowData);
  } else { 
    
    this.onAdd.emit(result.Data);
  }
  }
} );
});
}
```

Now getting error in browser, cannot read properties of undefined reading componentInstance

Comment: Sha, you should call to your API in "submit button" **without** close the modal. Only is is correct you close the modal and show the toast. BTW, try to edit your question, really it's hard to read it

Comment: @Eliseo, I cant do that as I have many components which will use that modal and the respective call to Api will be in the specific component

Comment: you needn't use close from the popup, you can use close from parent. Really I don't know about your requirements, but really the call to the service, as you say, should be in the "parent" component. Take a look to my answer, I hope give you any clue.

Comment: @Eliseo thanks for your help so far. I have uploaded the latest code snippet and still having some issues. Grateful if you can check pls

Comment: you should close the popup in subscribe function of submitSubject (in the custom-table.component.ts), **not** in the dynamic-form-component

Comment: @Eliseo noted. But im getting an error for component instance in openmodal() method :(

Comment: you have a `.` in your line:`const modalRef = this.ModalService.show((DynamicFormComponent), config, options).` it's a typo error?, else remove this `.`. NOTE: is in `if (result.Success == true && result.Data) { modalRef.close();...rest of your code...}`

Comment: @Eliseo, it's a typo only in my update. Its not recognising the componentInstance in my modalRef saying that property componentInstance does not exist on type of observable<ModalResult>

Comment: @Eliseo, another thing. The modal should be closed after the api call in food component right? So it should be based after the onAdd and on Edit i think

Comment: @Eliseo, any update plz? Stuck on it since days :((

Comment: Sha, I update again the answer. Really I don't know exactly how you have your code and your functions, so it's difficult to me be sure that it's all correct. Take a breath, think what we are doing and the order of events we get when we click on "submit" button.

Comment: @Eliseo, componentInstance is not working. Should we change the approach like programatically trigger a close event for the modal without closing it? :(

Comment: if you see the [API](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModal) you see that open return a [NgbModalRef](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModalRef) if you're open a new component the `componentInstance` is a reference of the component you has open. Are you open a component or a Template reference? try use `console.log(modalRef,modalRef.componentInstance)` to be sure that you get the correct values.

Comment: For me it is not open method, it is show method by a third party library given to me. The definition is like this show<T,R>(content: Type<T>, config?: Partial<T>, options?: NgbModalOptions): Observable<dsModalResult<R>>

Comment: @Eliseo, the class for dsModalResult is export declare class dsModalResult<T>{ Success: boolean; Data: T, constructor(data: T, success?: boolean}

Comment: ::glups:: I always thought that you're using ngb-bootstrap. The third part library is public? (if is public, can you indicate it?) Anyway I imagine that is "hardly" extends ngb-boostrap. In this case is **possible** that your ModalService have a property `activeInstances` that was an observable, see my another answer (perhaf you can declare: ngbmodalService=(this.ModalService as NgbModal)

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the `hide.bs.modal` event, based on your condition

```js
$("#exampleModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function(event) {
  if (!document.querySelector("#defaultCheck1").checked) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    Allow Closing
  </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is related to [ngb-modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)

Comment: I see. In that case OP should apply same reasoning to the event `beforeDismiss` [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModalOptions)

Comment: @ITgoldman, can you support to write a code snippet pls?

Comment: i don't know. if you make a working snippet  it would be easier to answer

Comment: @ITgoldman, had missed the food component html. Have a look if it is easier to get the flow

Answer (score 0):

Not use "close". Add to your component in modal a Subject, and subscribe when open. Is the component that open the popup who close the popup

```
//in your component in a popup
    @Input() form: FormGroup;
    submit:Subject<any>=new Subject<any>()

//in .html
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close"
           (click)="activeModal.dismiss()"
  ></button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Hello, {{ name }}!</p>
  <!--A typical form-->
  <div [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="name" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-outline-dark"
    <!--see that only emit one value to the "submit" subject -->
    (click)="submit.next(form.value)"
  >
    Close
  </button>
</div>
```

Then, when open

```
  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
    modalRef.componentInstance.form = this.form;
    modalRef.componentInstance.submit
      .pipe(takeUntil(modalRef.closed))
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        //I use a simple service that return "true" or "false"
        this.dataService.checkData(data.name).subscribe((res: any) => {
          if (res) modalRef.close(); //<--this close the popUp
        });
      });
  }
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzxqx9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown-basic.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown-basic.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdata-servicets.service.ts,src%2Findex.html) (only close if you write "Angular" in the "name")

NOTE: you can improve indicating the reason it's not valid the "form" or you can use a custom async validator.

**Update** a brief explain

In ngb-popup we can subscribe in the own function "show":

```
this.ModalService.show((DynamicFormComponent), config, options).subscribe(...)
```

Or use a variable and after subscribe

```
//get a reference of the "popup"
const modalRef = this.ModalService.show((DynamicFormComponent), config, options)

//Subcribe to it
modalRef.subscribe(...)
```

We need take the second approach.

If in our "DynamicFormComponent" we define "any public variable", we can access to it. This is the reason we can add to our DynamicFormComponent the variable

```
submitSubject:Subject<any>=new Subject<any>()
```

Now, we can "subscribe to this Subject", so

```
//really we use takeWhile to unsubscribe when the modal is closed
modalRef.componentInstance.submitSubject.subscribe((data: any) => {}
```

And in our DynamicFormComponent we don't use "close". instead of use close we "emit" a value to the subject

```
 // instead of use in .html
 (click)="activeModal.close(value)"
 //we use
 (click)="submitSubject.next(value)"
```

Now, all the code we had under subscribe when close, we use in the subscription of the subject. And remember that, if all is Ok, we need to close manually (by code) the popup, using

```
modalRef.close();
```

**Update**

```
openModal(rowData: any = null) {
    const config: Partial<DynamicFormComponent> = {
        form: this.form,
        data: rowData
    };

    const options: NgbModalOptions = { size: 'sm', centered: true };

    const modalRef = this.ModalService.show((DynamicFormComponent)
                                                  , config, options)

    modalRef.componentInstance.submitSubject.subscribe((data: any) => { 
       //we call to api to add the foodItem    
       this.api.request('foodItem', 'POST', data).subscribe({
          next: (response: any) => {
            if (response.message == 'Added Successfully.') {
                this._toastService.showSuccess('Food added.');

                //when is added  we close
                modalRef.close(); 

                //and emit according is update or insert
                if (rowData) {
                     const updatedRowData = { ...rowData, ...result.Data };
                     this.onEdit.emit(updatedRowData);
                } else { 
                     this.onAdd.emit(result.Data);
                }


            } else {
                this._toastService.showError(response.message);
            }
          },
          complete: () => this.getFood(),
          error: (error: any) => 
           this._toastService.showError(error.message)
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the question it's not related to ngb-bootstrap else a third part library.

It's looks like this library use internaly ngb-bootstrap, so, we **can try** to do the next to get the instance

```
  private ngbmodalService = inject(NgbModal); //<--inject the NgbModal
  //or
  private ngbmodalService=this.ModalService as NgbModal
  private modalRef:any;                    //declare a variable instance

                                    //subscribe to ngbmodalService.activeInstances
                                   //to give value to the "modalRef" var
  activeSubscription=this.ngbmodalService.activeInstances.subscribe(res=>{
    this.modalRef=res.length?res[0]:null
  })
```

In this way, when open

```
this.ModalService.show(...)
setTimeout(()=>{
   this.modalRef.componentInstance.submitSubject.subscribe(...)
})
```

And when close

```
this.modalRef.close() //<--close all the popup
```

NOTE: To know the public properties of an Object We can use some like

```
for (let key in this.ModalService) 
   console.log(key)
```

or simply use

```
console.log(this.ModalService)
```

to know the "properties" of the Object this.ModalService

**Update** Another idea using ViewChildren
if we declare in our component

```
@ViewChildren(DynamicFormComponent) dinamics:QueryList<DynamicFormComponent>
subcription=this.dinamic.changes(res=>{
   console.log(res.length,res.first,(res.first as any).submitSubject)
})
```

We can try to "get" the DynamicFormComponent and the "submitSubject"

Comment: I really appreciate ur help so far but casting it as NgbModal is saying 'Conversion of type 'dsModalService' to typw 'NgbModal' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other.if this was intentional, convert the experession to unknown first

Comment: I will post my updated code

Comment: updated but getting undefined on componentinstance

Comment: I dont' know about your "dsModalService". I feel that should to have a property that it's related to the "componentInstance", but really I don't know about this. You can try use `console.log(this.ModalService)` into your function open and look for something similar. Then use some like (it's only an example) `(this.ModalServices as any)._modalStack._modalRefs`

Comment: are the changes that I made in the openModal method correct in the way that u were saying?

Comment: Sincerly, I don't know. If we can not access to the "submitSubject" of the component we can not subscribe and my idea don't work :(